# erlang vim plugin like grep

Tags: vim, erlang

I used [vim-erlang-tags](https://github.com/vim-erlang/vim-erlang-tags) for long time.
But It's used to find the position where function or record defined.
when I want to find where functions invoked,or some atoms I have to use `grep -r`.
Is there some other tool can handle this.
thks.

Comment: https://github.com/syed/erlcscope is one solution.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is `vimgrep /module_name:fun_name/ src/*.erl | :copen`. But I usually go with `grep`in other tmux-window.